# Changing background color of selected item in recyclerview Not Working When I use Onclick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Changing the background color of the selected item in Recyclerview Not Working When I Call Bind function But When I Not Changing the Color OnClick Properly Working.

```
     public class Recycleview_List_Adapter extends
     RecyclerView.Adapter < Recycleview_List_Adapter.ViewHolder > {
     public final OnItemClickListener listener;
     int index = -1;
     private List < String > mData;
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     Context context;

     // data is passed into the constructor
     public Recycleview_List_Adapter(Context context, List < String > data, OnItemClickListener listener) {
         this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         this.mData = data;
         this.listener = listener;
         this.context = context;
     }

     // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
     @Override
     public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview2, parent, false);
         return new ViewHolder(view);
     }

     // binds the data to the TextView in each row
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         String animal = mData.get(position);
         holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
         holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 index = position;
                 notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
         });
         //holder.bind(holder.myTextView, listener);

         if (index == position) {
             holder.myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
             holder.myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
         } else {
             holder.myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#443d89"));
             holder.myTextView.setTypeface(holder.myTextView.getTypeface(),
                 Typeface.BOLD);
             holder.myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_boundary_rectangle);
         }
         holder.bind(holder.layout, listener, mData.get(position));
     }

     // total number of rows
     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
         return mData.size();
     }

     // convenience method for getting data at click position
     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return (position);
     }

     public String getItem(int id) {
         return mData.get(id);
     }

     public interface OnItemClickListener {
         void onItemClick(View view, int position, String s);
     }

     // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
     public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         TextView myTextView;
         LinearLayout layout;

         ViewHolder(View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.al);
             layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
         }
         //This is my Bind Function
         public void bind(final View view, final OnItemClickListener listener, final String list) {
             itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     listener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), list);
                 }
             });


         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: "Not Changing the Color OnClick Properly Working" here which colour you mean?

Comment: Thanks For Reply But I Am already Post the ans thanks

Comment: `View itemView` is parent of `LinearLayout layout` and you added listeners for both so parent is getting called

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Recycleview_List_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycleview_List_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    public final OnItemClickListener listener;
    int index = -1;
    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    public Recycleview_List_Adapter(Context context, List<String> data, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                listener.onItemClick(mData.get(position));

            }
        });

        if (index == position) {
            holder.myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            holder.myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        } else {
            holder.myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#443d89"));
            holder.myTextView.setTypeface(holder.myTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_boundary_rectangle);
        }

    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (position);
    }

    public String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String s);
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView myTextView;
        LinearLayout layout;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.al);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }




        }

    }
}
```